# Delete rows when two conditions is complete in a Pandas dataframe with python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following DataFrame :

```
  column1  column2  columns3  column4
0       A        1         2      3.0
1       B        1         2      3.0
2       B        1         2      NaN
3       B        1         2      NaN
```

I'm trying to delete all rows that have the value "B" in **column1** and a blank cell (or a NaN value) in **column4**.

This does not work:

```
for row in df.iterrows():
    if (df.column1.items() == "B"):
        if (df.column4.isnull()):
            df.drop()
```

And this does not work either:

```
for row in df.iterrows():
    if (df.column1.items() == "B") & (df.column4.isna()):
        df.drop()
```

I do not have an error when I run but nothing happens when I print the dataframe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use multiple conditions and [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
out = df[df['column1'].ne('B') | df['column4'].notna()]
```

which, according to [DeMorgan's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) is equivalent to:

```
out = df[~(df['column1'].eq('B') & df['column4'].isna())]
```

Output:

```
  column1  column2  columns3  column4
0       A        1         2      3.0
1       B        1         2      3.0
```

Intermediates for the first approach:

```
  column1  column2  columns3  column4  col1 ≠ b  col4.notna()  (col1 ≠ b) OR col4.notna()
0       A        1         2      3.0      True          True                        True
1       B        1         2      3.0     False          True                        True
2       B        1         2      NaN     False         False                       False
3       B        1         2      NaN     False         False                       False
```

Intermediates for the second approach:

```
  column1  column2  columns3  column4  col1 == b  col4.isna()  (col1 == b) AND col4.isna()      ~
0       A        1         2      3.0      False         True                        False   True
1       B        1         2      3.0       True         True                        False   True
2       B        1         2      NaN       True        False                         True  False
3       B        1         2      NaN       True        False                         True  False
```

Comment: @ScottBoston it's actually relatively easy. For DeMorgan's law, invert the comparison operators (= → ≠ ; > →≤ ; etc.), swap AND / OR ; invert the result (`~`) ;)

Comment: And I realized I had a wrong copy paste :D see update for a fix of the second approach

Answer (score 0):

I would solve it as follows:

```
adjusted_df = df[
                 ~(
                    (df['column1'] == "B") &   #Check1
                    (df['column4'].isnull())  #Check2
                  ) 
                 ]
```

This remains readable and straight forward.
Note: the brackets around each check is important, otherwise this will not work.

Comment: The logic is incorrect and `&` would cause any row B in column1 (but not NA in col4), or NA in col4 but not B in col1 to be discarded, incorrectly. Also `~(df['column4').isnull())` could be replaced by `df['column4').notnull()`